# Convert from Long to hex

Tags: java, hex, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I want to change to value of the major and minor of my beacon by calling a shell script from a java code.
If for example I want to set the value of the Major to `39321`, I have to pass a string with the value `99 99` as parameter to the shell code.
If I want to set it to `34866`, I have to pass the hex code `88 32`.
How can I convert from a long number like the 39321 to this two character composed hex number like `99 99`?

Comment: Format it with "%x" is not enough ?

Comment: Or `Long.toHexString`?

Comment: Long.toHexString will change 39321 to 0000000000000000000000000000003339333231 and not 99 99. "%x" is just for formatting it will also not change 39321 to "99 99"

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37709287/1461050

Answer (score 0):

You can use **toHexString(long i)** method from **Long** class.

For example :

```
Long.toHexString(39321)
```

It returns a string representation of the long argument as an unsigned integer in base 16.

Comment: This will return 0000000000000000000000000000003339333231, I am expecting to have 99 99 as result.

Comment: @Celiiine I got String result **9999** when testing with my eclipse. I am using **jdk1.8.0_72** and running on window 8.